# Reading a single column from csv using perl

Tags: perl, csv

file has data like this:

```
S_No        S_Name          Acc_Num     Total_Amount
1            Larry            1521          18000
```

To read a column from `csv` for this purpose I wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my$column_separator = qr/,/;
my $column_number = "3";
my$file = "/home/Admin/Documents/new (copy).csv";
open(my$FILE,">>","$file") or die "$!";
while (<$FILE>){
  my @columns = split(/$column_separator/);
  print $columns[$column_number] ,"\n";
}
close $FILE;
```

But this script is throwing an error.

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at another.pl line 12, <$FILE> line from 1 to 11..
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: The program you show doesn't have 27 lines. Please show your actual code.

Comment: I edited my question please see once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that the column is empty. That's why it is undefined. You need to add a check and handle the case that it is empty. You can do that in two ways:

- add a condition and not output empty columns at all

  ```
  print $columns[$column_number], "\n" if $columns[$column_number];
  ```
- output an empty line if the value is not defined

  ```
  print( ( $columns[$column_number] // q{} ), "\n");
  ```

---

Here are some more comments: You are `use`ing Text::CSV, but then you are not using it to read anything.

What you are instead doing is reading the file line by line, but there are a few things that you need to add and change:

- change the mode of your [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) call from `>>` to `<` because `>>` means *append*, but you want to *read*
- [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the input to remove trailing newlines

All of this results in the following code.

```
open(my $FILE,">>","$file") or die "$!";
while (<$FILE>) {
  chomp;
  my @columns = split(/$column_separator/);
  print ( $columns[$column_number] // q{} ), "\n";
}
```

You should also read up on [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) and learn to use it as it will help with a lot of common pitfalls for CSV files.

Comment: showing error `print (...) interpreted as function at another.pl line 13.
Useless use of a constant in void context at another.pl line 13.
Unknown open() mode '' at another.pl line 9.`

Comment: print (...) interpreted as function at another.pl line 13.
Useless use of a constant in void context at another.pl line 13.

Comment: I don't know what you have in line 13.

Comment: works fine now... but it is not extracting that third column values

Comment: With `$foo[3]` you are extracting the *fourth* column. The index starts at `0`.

Comment: even though if i place 2 instead of 3 still I could't getting desired output :(

Comment: You set your separator to `,`, but in your example input the columns are aligned using whitespace....

Comment: I set `,` this operator only